# so break statement just break out the inner for loop or both in c

Tags: c, loops, break

1.so break statement just break out the inner for loop or both?

```
for(j=0;j<n;j++)
{
    for(k=0;k<n;k++)
    {
        if(grid[j][k]=='p')
        {
            x=j;
            y=k;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: inner loop: as any documentation/basic tutorial  would tell you. AND as you could easily verify for yourself!

Comment: Think of the `break` statement works as LIFO principle when dealing with multiple inner loops. BTW, this should have been easily found out yourself by keeping debug messages.

Comment: Usually it turns out that there's a whole other problem behind questions like this. Is there some problem you're trying to solve with `break` and it's not doing what you assume it should?

Comment: so what shoul i do to exit looping as soon as grid[j][k]=='p'

Comment: @RohitVerma If you want to know how to exit nested loop, edit your question to reflect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`break` will only break out the inner loop. If you need to break out as soon as you found the element, use `goto`. Though you can avoid `goto` in this case using other techniques such as setting a flag. In my opinion, `goto` is the clean choice in this usage, especially when the loop is deeply nested.

```
for(j=0;j<n;j++)
{
    for(k=0;k<n;k++)
    {
        if(grid[j][k]=='p')
        {
            x=j;
            y=k;
            goto found;
        }
    }
}
found:
//other processing
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only break out of the current scope in C as C works in a "Last In, First Out" system.

Within 2 loops, you can only break out of the scope of the loop you are currently in. So you would need to set a flag, then break, and then in the outer loop, check for that flag and then if that flag exists, reset the flag and break.

Answer (score 0):

`break` only breaks from the immediate loop in which it is used. For breaking out of remaining loops use `goto` or `flags`. If you cannot use `goto` then set flags. Here is how your code looks when using flags:

```
int flag = 0; //set a flag and initialize it to zero
for(j=0;j<n;j++)
{
  for(k=0;k<n;k++)
   {
     if(grid[j][k]=='p')
      {
        x=j;
        y=k;
        flag = 1;  // set flag to 1
        break;
      }
    if (flag == 1) break;
   }  
 if (flag == 1) break;   
}
```

Comment: pls dont mind if am wrong .... but since first break; is breaking out inner loop... so do i need to use first if(flag==1) break; statement ??

Comment: The first `break` is breaking out of the `if` loop not the inner `for` loop. Since, as per your need, you want to break out of remaining loops too, use a `break` for each of remaining loops you want to get out of. Thanks for the comment. Please up vote the answer if it helped you! :)